# Are there any obvious reasons my node.js react app is not recognizing any index.html file?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

You can see the app here: https://02e7822e.ngrok.io

[git repo](https://github.com/joshua-yan/summarAIze)

My main problem is that index.html somehow never got hooked up, which means

1) the website doesn't scale at all for mobile devices

2) no favicon

[image]

Anything obvious I'm missing? I have built websites before but the index.js has always looked a little different every time, so here it is for reference:

```
import AppBar from '../components/AppBar';
import Block from '../components/Block';
import React from "react";

class Index extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar/>
                <Block/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Index;
```

In previous websites I have been able to use ReactDOM and document.getElementByID to (I think) make some sort of reference to index.html but I tried that and only got syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you used `create-react-app` and changed the folder structure all around.... don't do that.

Here is a link to the official folder structure:

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/folder-structure

Also.  When using a server along with React I have seen a folder structure where the server is kept in the root of the application, and then `React` is kept in a separate `client` folder.

```
my-main-app-folder
```

```
my-main-app-folder/
  client/ (This is the folder where React lives)
    public/
      index.html
      favicon.ico
    node_modules/
    src/
      App.js
      index.js
    package.json
    README.md
  .gitignore
  server.js
  package.json
  package-lock.json
  README.md
```

Something similar to this

Comment: To add onto that, this is the official folder structure of create-react-app: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/folder-structure

Comment: Going to add that onto my answer for visibility.

Comment: I just figured out I built my app off of next.js and it's incompatible with CRA.. woe is me